# Performance hit when connecting through mysqli and PDO?

Tags: php, mysqli, pdo

I'm switching over to PDO, but not all my code has been converted yet, so for ever page load I'm connecting twice:

First, the old fashioned way:

```
$db_handler = mysqli_connect($localhost, $username, $pass);
mysqli_select_db($db_handler,$database);
```

And a second time, the modern way:

```
$DBH = new PDO("mysql:host=$dblocalhost;dbname=$database", $dbusername, $dbpassword);
```

How 'expensive' is this technique from a performance standpoint? Should I avoid it by all means?

Comment: The hit for what? PDO? Or connecting twice?

Comment: @EdCottrell Hit for the total performance of the script/page when using 2 connections instead of 1.

Answer (score 0):

There's no real noticeable performance hit, but you could run into weird situations in extreme cases, especially if you use table locks. As a short term solution you could try to do so, but I assume the thorough testing involved would completely overshadow the effort to it properly all at once.

Do it properly with PDO and don't overcomplicate. Supporting two connections at the same time is definitely going to be a very dirty solution and will introduce new bugs into the code.